# Accounts.createUser create users, but only from the server and not allow the client to create user

Tags: meteor

first excuse my writing, I'm using google translator.

What I want is to create users meteor, but only from the server and not allow the client to create users.

try putting

```
Accounts.validateNewUser (function () {
    return false; 
});
```

but it denies me create users to the server (which I do not want)

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Accounts.config`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config) for that purpose. Just anywhere in your server code do

```
Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation: true,
});
```

Comment: Ha! I should have known they'd have built something a bit easier than my suggestion...

Comment: Thank you very much, it served me the answer, good luck and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add some kind of un-guessable string to the `profile` key when you create a user on the server, check for that key in the `validateNewUser` function and then remove it immediately using `observe` on an appropriate cursor.

On the server you would have:

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function(user) {
    return (user.profile && user.profile.createUserKey === [KEY]);
});

Meteor.users.find().observe({
    added: function(user) {
        Meteor.users.update(user, {$unset: {'profile.createUserKey': true}});
    }
});
```

And then your server-side `createUser` line looks like this (along with any other data you want to pass in the profile):

```
Accounts.createUser({username: [USERNAME], password: [PASSWORD], profile: {createUserKey: [KEY]}});
```

Assuming you don't publish the validation function anywhere (like Github), a client will have no way of knowing what the key is and would thus be unable to create a new user.  If you don't trust yourself not to push it to Github or similar, store the key in an unpublished collection in your MongoDB and then pull it out on server start-up - that's what I do.

**NOTE** I think it's slightly unsatisfactory that I'm using a cursor here as it would be far better to remove the key in an `onCreateUser` callback, but this seems to be called *before* `validateNewUser`, so it's no use here.  The alternatives are using your own modified version of the `createUser` function in the Accounts package, which probably isn't too tough but is a little involved to go into here, or just leaving the key in the user document and making sure you don't publish it.

Comment: Nice hacking, but it's far from the easiest way :)

Comment: Thank you very much, chooses to hubert response. But this answer, I opened the way for other functions I want to implement. agradesco him much response.